# Create a function that joins inputs string and return if there's no input

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I came across this question in an assessment but could not finish it. I still can't figure it out though

```
console.log(
    fx("append").fx("me").fx()
)
//this prints append me

function fx (value) {
    //answer
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(
    fx("append").fx("me").fx()
)
//this prints append me

function fx (value) {
    return {
      fx: function (newValue) {
        if (!newValue) return value
        
        return fx([value, newValue].join(' '))
      }
    }
}
```